# How to set debugger parameters in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

While using Delphi XE4, I can access Debugger Parameters in RAD Studio by following path

```
Project --> Options --> Debugger --> Parameters
```

But I am not able find the same in Delphi 7. Where can I set Debugger Parameters in Delphi 7?

Actually when I run my application from command line like this

C:> myApplication.exe 12345, it works fine. My application is using `ParamStr(1)` to set some initial values. So I set 12345 in my Delphi XE4 RAD Studio by going on above path

```
 Project --> Options --> Debugger --> Parameters
```

Same I have to set in my Delphi 7 application, but I am not finding the path where to set this parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in the 'Run' menu, select 'Parameters...' and that opens the 'Run Parameters' dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start --> Parameters (I only have a german IDE, so the menu items may have a slightly different title)

there you can define Host Application, Parameters and Working Dir